Typing accent ague (é) on Windows 10
I am using Extended English Keyboard and would like to enter French accents using keyboard shortcut keys in Windows 10. In MS Word and MS Outlook all works fine except for the accent ague (é). In MS Word or Outlook, when I use the shortcut supposed to be used for accent ague Ctrl+ apostrophe key ', I get accent grave (è) instead. Thus, it seems I can use two methods to type accent grave:
`+ letter-to-be-accented
or
Ctrl + apostrophe key + letter-to-be-accented.
At the same time, in other applications installed in Windows 10 (web browser - no matter which, MS Excel etc.) I can only input accent grave using
`+ letter-to-be-accented
(no ç, no circonflexe, nothing except accent grave like à or è).
Any ideas?

Thank God for the invention of the AZERTY keyboard :-)

Go and check your keyboard layout on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdukx - when you hover with your mouse pointer on the AltGr key, you can see the relevant french letters you need: ç = AltGr + c é = AltGr + e

@Dominique QWERTY vs AZERTY has nothing to do with it. There are also QWERTY keyboards with added é etc keys. It really depends on what language the keyboard was made for.

@LPChip: that's my point: AZERY keyboards are made for languages with "é" letters :-)

@Dominique and those same AZERTY keyboards have a version with QWERTY, and that is my point. ;)

@Dominique if you have no choice, then I have found that the Canadian QWERTY Multilingual is the best in terms of accented character support. Of course nowadays you have AZERTY+ and BÉPO which are standardized in France, and there are other Dvorak-inspired alternatives.

Have you heard of wincompose? Extremely useful software, both for mathematics and multilingual text.

The key `¹ is indeed used for è, but '² is used for é.
The `¹ key is also the ~ key.
The '² key is also the " key.
The '² key is also used to type the ç (' + c).
I've added ¹ and ² after the keys to identify that they are indeed different keys.

There is also the option to define your own keyboard layout, or to modify your current layout with MSKLC.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134
You can define your own keys for those accents amongst other things.

It seems that following the information on some web sites I was using wrong key shortcuts (Crtl instead of AltGr). The comment by 1NN contributed to my having spotted the mistake. In MS Word and Outlook I could get most of the required accents even with Crtl which blurred the whole picture.
